# how to set a variable as factor in global environment

Tags: r

I have a list of dfs `lst`, and each df in `lst` have variable "ID". It is possible to set "ID" as a factor at once, in stead of set one by one?

Is this called setting up a variable in global environment? I might used the wrong term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can loop over the `list` with `lapply`, and `transform`

```
lst <- lapply(lst, transform, ID = factor(ID))
```

---

Or if we have an object with string 'ID' in the global env

```
v1 <- "ID"
lst <- lapply(lst, function(x) {
        x[[v1]] <- factor(x[[v1]])
        x})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the **`tidyverse`**:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

map(lst, ~.x%>%mutate(ID=as.factor(ID))
```

an example with the iris dataset:

```
#first transform the Species into a character variable:
iris<-iris%>%mutate(Species=as.character(Species))

#second, create an additional iris dataframe for the list
iris2<-iris
lst<-list(df1=iris, df2=iris2)

#Then call map with the mutating function:
map(lst, ~.x%>%mutate(Species=as.factor(Species)))
```